# Apply Meltdown patches to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I follow the upgrade guide here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Upgrades

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

to perform the kernel-level patches to Ubuntu 14.04LTS https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3524-1/

However, I don't know how to check if the patches are successfully applied or not.

Is there a way to check and certify the patches?

Comment: I guess KPTI is unclear to newbies.

Comment: I think that KPTI only addresses Meltdown.

Comment: Now I tried all commands mentioned in the KPTI post. All claims the patch is not there. But how do I know if Ubuntu's official patch is installed or not? I will be assuming if it is installed then my system is fine for now. Just how to check is my question.

Comment: are you using an intell processor? meltdown does not apply to non intell chips.

Comment: Yes, Intel® Xeon® processor E5-2620

Comment: sudo less /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep CONFIG_PAGE_TABLE_ISOLATION